# Image in HTML email signature varies in size

Tags: html, email, outlook

In the email signature I'm making for my company I have an embedded image on the left. When I preview the code in Chrome or my IDE the image is sized properly taking up the same height as the three lines of evenly-spaced text to its right. However, when others in my company receive emails from me, sometimes the image is significantly taller than the lines of text next to it. How do I ensure that my image stays a consistent size across devices and email clients?

```html
    <html>
    <STYLE>A {text-decoration: none;} </STYLE><body>
        <table data-mysignature-date="2019-09-17T19:52:14.752Z" data-mysignature-is-paid="0" width="500" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td
                               valign="center" width="0" style="padding:0 8px 0 0;vertical-align: middle;"><img alt="TETON Sports" width="100" style="width:67px;" src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/88530bbf8421421caccd471108c1fc18/email-icon.png">
                            </td>
    
                            <td style="font-size:1em;padding:0 0 0 0;vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="line-height: 1.4;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:90%;color: #000001;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#000001;">
                                                [COMPANY NAME]
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding: 0px 0;">
                                            <div style="color:#000001;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                                                <b> Austin Berenyi </b>
                                                <span style="color:#FF9E18;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;"> <b>//</b> </span>
                                                <span style="color:#54565A;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;"> <i>Graphic Designer</i> </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#54565A;" <span><a href="mailto:austin@tetonsports.com" target="_blank" style="font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color: #54565A;"><i>austin@company.com</i></a></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may sounds naive, but just try to specify height of your img:

```
<img alt="TETON Sports" style="width:67px; height: 48px;" src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/88530bbf8421421caccd471108c1fc18/email-icon.png">
```

In addition try to always set **font-size** of text (px or em) and try to avoid these values as percents.

Comment: This, and remove or make your `height` attribute consistent. Original question has the height set with inline CSS and a `height` attribute, which have conflicting values.

Comment: @cccn I tried that, but when viewed on the Outlook desktop app on a Windows PC the icon is still about 30% bigger than expected.

Comment: @TomFaltesek which height attribute are you referring to? I'm only seeing one height value, and it's the one I added after cccn's suggestion.

Comment: My mistake. I meant to say `width` attribute.

Comment: `<img alt="TETON Sports" width="100" style="width:67px;" src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/88530bbf8421421caccd471108c1fc18/email-icon.png">` has a width defined.

Comment: @AustinBerenyi hm, it's weird. Are you sure that image is bigger, or maybe font-size is smaller? I just updated my answear